# CRM 2011 Custom Aspx Page in IFRame

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am in kind of strange situation and cannot figure out whats the problem.

I have a Custom Page named `/ISV/Portal/Portal.aspx` and Custom Configuration Path `/ISV/CustomConfiguration/Web.config`

In Config File i have ServerName, user Login(i.e Administrator), Password to Create Service.
When account form is viewed by Development Manager of CRM the page is diplayed

and working fine, but the Page is not shown to any other Persons including users having Administrator Role

The Following Message is Displayed:

```
Unable to change domain logon name
You do not have the necessary permissions to change the domain logon name for this user
```

Comment: I removed the generic "CRM" tag and the non-relevant crm online tag. Which CRM version are you on ? Remove the tag regarding the wrong one.

Comment: Also, what does the page do ? Issue might not be related to CRM. If you run it on its own (faking any form-related data exchange) does it work ?

Comment: If i run it on its own like giving the specific url of the page
like:
http://crm2011/isv/Portal/Portal.aspx

The Same error comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After surfing the Internet:

I was not able to make my aspx page work successfully.

At last i hosted my webpage as an independent Website:

1. Hosted separate Asp.net Website
2. Published my Custom Page in that directory.
3. Gave access rights to read/write the C:/TempImages
4. And Changed the IFrame url to my new location.

Now it's working like a charm :)